# Missing payment fields on membership renewal

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, joomla

[image: missing fields for recording payment of membership]

Hi,
for some reason the fields for payment of the renewal of membership are missing.
Is it something with configuration?
Version is 4.7, but the issue was there even before the upgrade
br,
M

Answer (score 1):

In the screenshot the "membership organisation and type" field is empty.  Did you blank it out or have you disabled the relevant membership type?  Without  a membership type with an associated fee there won't be any payment fields.

Comment: Hi,i just blanked it. It has associated valid membership